# Javascript: How to add new key->value to first order?

Tags: javascript, object, multidimensional-array

I have this:

```
data_a = [{
    "name": "Johnny", 
    "sport":"Racing"
}];

data_b = [{
    "member": 12345
}];
```

How to combine into:

```
data_new = [{
    "member": 12345,
    "name": "Johnny", 
    "sport":"Racing"
}];
```

Any answer are greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Object.assign`

```
var data_new = [];
data_new[0] = Object.assign( {}, data_a[0], data_b[0])
```

If this has to be **extended for all items of `data_a`** (and assuming `data_a.length` is same as `data_b.length`), then

```
var data_new = data_a.map( (s, i) => Object.assign( {}, s, data_b[i]) )
```

**Demo**

```js
var data_a = [{
    "name": "Johnny", 
    "sport":"Racing"
}];

var data_b = [{
    "member": 12345
}];
var data_new = data_a.map( (s, i) => Object.assign( {}, s, data_b[i]) )
console.log( data_new );
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much!

Comment: @heavylildude Glad it worked for you. Please accept and upvote the answer that has helped you.

Answer (score 0):

```
data_c = [{...data_b[0], ...data_a[0]}]
```

pasting from my node console

```
> data_a = [{
...     "name": "Johnny", 
...     "sport":"Racing"
... }];
[ { name: 'Johnny', sport: 'Racing' } ]
> 
> data_b = [{
...     "member": 12345
... }];
[ { member: 12345 } ]
> 
> data_a
[ { name: 'Johnny', sport: 'Racing' } ]
> data_b
[ { member: 12345 } ]
> data_c = [{...data_b[0], ...data_a[0]}]
[ { member: 12345, name: 'Johnny', sport: 'Racing' } ]
> data_c
[ { member: 12345, name: 'Johnny', sport: 'Racing' } ]
>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a new array for all arrays to join the object at the same index.

```js
var data_a = [{ name: "Johnny", sport:"Racing" }],
    data_b = [{ member: 12345 }],
    result = [data_a, data_b].reduce((r, a) => {
        a.forEach((o, i) => r[i] = Object.assign({}, r[i], o));
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```